# JSONPath find in list

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

Let's say I have a JSON like this:

```json
{
  "roles": [
    "role1",
    "role2",
    "super_role1",
    "super_role2"
  ]
}
```

And I want to filter with JSONPath to only match 'super*' and get a list with the matches:

```py
["super_role1", "super_role2"]
```

What should be my path expression ?

I have tried .roles['super*'], and other variants but I cannot find a way to simply filter on the strings of a list.

Comment: Did you try regular expressions within a jsonpath expression?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something with actual expressions? A quick google gave me https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html#filters

Comment: I have not seen a way to filter on values in the list directly

Comment: It seems to be dependent upon the engine. 
When I use https://jsonpath.com/ with the query `$.roles[?(@ =='role1')]` I get a single result, as expected. However, it does not support regexes, || (ors) or in clauses, it seems. 
It does not accept `$.roles[?(@ =='role1' || @=='role2')]`, which *does* work at https://codebeautify.org/jsonpath-tester 
To be honest, jsonpath seems like a hot mess (and don't mix it up with groovy's jsonpath-like thing, which works entirely different *again*).